# Complex leaderboard calculations with SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select, phpmyadmin

I'm facing a big problem here, because of my non-existant skills with SQL.

I actually have this table.

[image]

I'd like to rank users on each levels like this,

[image]

so I can then add each rank of each user on each levels, to make a global ranking.

[image]

I'm pretty new to mySQL, so I'd like to know if it's possible with one SELECT query or if it's possible.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of MySQL? In 8.x is easy. In 5.x it could be cumbersome.

Comment: Why does `C` has a score of 1 in the global ranking? Shouldn't it have a score of 2?

Comment: Why does `B` as global rank 2 instead of `A` (that has global rank 3)? They should have the same rank, right?

Comment: How can I se the mySQL version?
Oh yes, I failed it a little bit.. C should have a score of 2, and B should be 2 too, but I fact it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` functions to do what you want. For example:

```
with
a as (
  select
    level, user, score,
    rank() over(partition by level order by score) as rk
  from t
),
r as (
  select
    user,
    sum(rk) as score
  from a
  group by user
)
select
  rank() over(order by score),
  user, score
from r
```

Note: Your expected results are a little bit confusing so you'll probably need to tweak this query once you answer the questions I asked.

Comment: Then it's MySQL 5.x or older.

Comment: So I can't do what I want with that version?